# Internet Explorer doesn't sets to visible (c#)

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, windows-services, internet-explorer-9

I'm working on a windows service that loads pages from a csv files using different proxies on Internet Explorer and take an screenshot of it.

The problem I have (besides I can't delete index.dat, but that is a different story), is that when I want to make Internet Explorer visible (IE.Visible = true), it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Here is part of the code. The "WriteLog" functions are for me to check when running the release version what is happening (milestones).

Using Windows 7, Internet Explorer 9 and Visual Studio 2010.

```
static void testSite (string url, int rowNum)
{
    WebLoaderHelper.WriteLog("TS: Variables");
    int width, height, hwnd;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Stopwatch chronometer = new Stopwatch();

    //Init Variables
    isDocumentComplete = false;
    isNavigateError = false;
    errorCode = 200;

    long result;
    InternetExplorer IE = null;
    IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    string proxy;

    proxy = getProxy();

    IE.DocumentComplete += new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(IE_DocumentComplete);
    IE.NavigateError += new DWebBrowserEvents2_NavigateErrorEventHandler(IE_NavigateError);


    //Helper.setWindowState(IE.HWND, 2); 
    WebLoaderHelper.WriteLog("TS: IE VISIBLE");
    try
    {
        IE.Visible = Boolean.Parse(Properties.Settings.Default.IEVisible);
        WebLoaderHelper.WriteLog("TS: IE VISIBLE:" + IE.Visible.ToString());
        IE.Visible = true;
        WebLoaderHelper.WriteLog("TS: IE VISIBLE (true):" + IE.Visible.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        WebLoaderHelper.WriteLog("TS: IE VISIBLE EXCEPTION:" + e.ToString());
        WebLoaderHelper.WriteLog("TS: IE VISIBLE:" + IE.Visible.ToString());
        IE.Visible = true;
        WebLoaderHelper.WriteLog("TS: IE VISIBLE again:" + IE.Visible.ToString());
    }

    WebLoaderHelper.WriteLog("TS: Watches");
    stopWatch.Start();
    chronometer.Start();
    WebLoaderHelper.WriteLog("TS: Navigate");
    IE.Navigate(url.ToString());

    //Log Start DateTime
    ResultsDT.Rows[rowNum][0] = DateTime.Now;

    WebLoaderHelper.WriteLog("TS: While complete");
    while (!isDocumentComplete)
    {
        if (chronometer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds > 60)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("Proxy: " + proxy);
            sb.AppendLine("site: " + url);
            sb.AppendLine("Took: " + chronometer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString() + "seconds and isn't complete. Breaking while.");
            sb.AppendLine();
            WebLoaderHelper.WriteLog(sb.ToString());
            WebLoaderHelper.WriteEToErrorLog(sb.ToString());
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            chronometer.Stop();
            break;
         }
    }


    //Artificially add half a second, to let all images load
    Thread.Sleep(500);

    //Take Pic
    WebLoaderHelper.WriteLog("TS: Take Pic");
    if (IE.Visible)
    {
        WebLoaderHelper.WriteLog("TS: IE Visible PIC!");
        try
        {
            width = IE.Width;
            height = IE.Height;
            WebLoaderHelper.getScreenShot(IE.HWND, width, height, proxy, url);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("Proxy: " + proxy);
            sb.AppendLine("site: " + url);
            sb.AppendLine(e.Message);
            sb.AppendLine();

            WebLoaderHelper.WriteEToErrorLog(sb.ToString());
            WebLoaderHelper.WriteLog("TS: IE VISIBLE PIC but EXCEPTION: " + e.ToString());
         }
     }

     WebLoaderHelper.WriteLog("TS: Stop everything");

     IE.Stop();
     IE.Quit();
     stopWatch.Stop();
     result = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;


     try
     {
          cleanProcessList();
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Problem with cleaning process list");
          WebLoaderHelper.WriteLog("TS: Problem with cleaning process list");
     }


      //Log Result
      ResultsDT.Rows[rowNum][3] = result;
      ResultsDT.Rows[rowNum][4] = errorCode;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer isn't supported for use by background automation running in Services. I wouldn't be surprised to learn that it explicitly refuses to become visible in this configuration.

It's not clear why you would *want* to delete index.dat, but no, you won't ever be able to do that, nor should you want to. If you want to clear the browser's cache, there are WinINET APIs for that.